# how to change speed value from 0,002543535 to 0

Tags: c#

im trying to change speed value from 0,002543535 to 0 but i dont know how to do it and where to put the code.

```
using AssettoCorsaSharedMemory;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AssettoCorsa ac = new AssettoCorsa();
            ac.StaticInfoInterval = 500; // Get StaticInfo updates ever 5 seconds
            ac.StaticInfoUpdated += ac_StaticInfoUpdated; // Add event listener for StaticInfo
            ac.PhysicsInterval = 500;
            ac.PhysicsUpdated += ac_PhysicsUpdated;
            

        ac.Start(); // Connect to shared memory and start interval timers 

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ac_StaticInfoUpdated(object sender, StaticInfoEventArgs e)
        {
            // Print out some data from StaticInfo
          //  Console.WriteLine("StaticInfo");
          //  Console.WriteLine("  Car Model: " + e.StaticInfo.CarModel);
          //  Console.WriteLine("  Track:     " + e.StaticInfo.Track);
          //  Console.WriteLine("  Max RPM:   " + e.StaticInfo.MaxRpm);

        }

        static void ac_PhysicsUpdated(object sender, PhysicsEventArgs e)
        {
            // Print out some data from StaticInfo

              Console.WriteLine("  Speed:   " + e.Physics.SpeedKmh);
          //  Console.WriteLine("  Gear:   " + e.Physics.Gear);
          //  Console.WriteLine("  TC:   " + e.Physics.TC);
              Console.WriteLine("  RPM:   " + e.Physics.Rpms);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is code where SpeedKmh is declared

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AssettoCorsaSharedMemory
{
    public class PhysicsEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public PhysicsEventArgs (Physics physics)
        {
            this.Physics = physics;
        }

        public Physics Physics { get; private set; }
    }

    [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Coordinates
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;
    }

    [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [Serializable]
    public struct Physics
    {
        public int PacketId;
        public float Gas;
        public float Brake;
        public float Fuel;
        public int Gear;
        public int Rpms;
        public float SteerAngle;
        public float SpeedKmh;

        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public float[] Velocity;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public float[] AccG;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] WheelSlip;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] WheelLoad;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] WheelsPressure;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] WheelAngularSpeed;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] TyreWear;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] TyreDirtyLevel;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] TyreCoreTemperature;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] CamberRad;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] SuspensionTravel;

        public float Drs;
        public float TC;
        public float Heading;
        public float Pitch;
        public float Roll;
        public float CgHeight;

        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
        public float[] CarDamage;

        public int NumberOfTyresOut;
        public int PitLimiterOn;
        public float Abs;

        public float KersCharge;
        public float KersInput;
        public int AutoShifterOn;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public float[] RideHeight;

        // since 1.5
        public float TurboBoost;
        public float Ballast;
        public float AirDensity;

        // since 1.6
        public float AirTemp;
        public float RoadTemp;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public float[] LocalAngularVelocity;
        public float FinalFF;

        // since 1.7
        public float PerformanceMeter;
        public int EngineBrake;
        public int ErsRecoveryLevel;
        public int ErsPowerLevel;
        public int ErsHeatCharging;
        public int ErsisCharging;
        public float KersCurrentKJ;
        public int DrsAvailable;
        public int DrsEnabled;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] BrakeTemp;

        // since 1.10
        public float Clutch;

        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] TyreTempI;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] TyreTempM;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] TyreTempO;

        // since 1.10.2
        public int IsAIControlled;

        // since 1.11
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public Coordinates[] TyreContactPoint;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public Coordinates[] TyreContactNormal;
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public Coordinates[] TyreContactHeading;
        public float BrakeBias;

        // since 1.12
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public float[] LocalVelocity;
    }
}
```

when my car is not moving im getting speed value like on the picture, anyone know how to change it to just 0? _______________________________________________________________________________________

[image]

Comment: Whut? Picture looks like `0 km/h` to me...

Comment: im talking about console, its 0,002432423. I want it to show just 0

Comment: Do whatever you did to get the graphics to show 0 km/h? (that way it's consistent?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably here (didn't see anywhere else it is possible):

```
static void ac_PhysicsUpdated(object sender, PhysicsEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Speed:   " + e.Physics.SpeedKmh); // <---
    // ...
}
```

You can use `System.Math.Round` method to get nearest integer value or cast explicitly to `int` type:

```
float speed = e.Physics.SpeedKmh; // <-- 0.002543535 (float type)
double dRoundedSpeed = Math.Round(speed); // <-- 0 (double type)
float fRoundedSpeed = (float)Math.Round(speed); // <-- 0 (float type)
int iRoundedSpeed = (int)speed; // <-- 0 (int type)
```